# How do I make the code below to accept both float and int as input?

Tags: python

How do I make the code below to accept both float and int as input?

```
'''This program helps you solve quadratic equation using

the quadratic formula principle

Quadratic formula, x = -b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)/2a

'''

from math import sqrt

try:
    a = int(input('Input the value of a: '))
    b = int(input('Input the value of b: '))
    c = int(input('Input the value of c: '))
    numeratorA = (-b) + sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))
    numeratorB = (-b) - sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))
    denominator = 2 * a
    root1 = numeratorA/denominator
    root2 = numeratorB/denominator
    print('The roots are:', root1, "and", root2)

except:
    print('Enter only numbers!')?
```

Comment: Change `int(...)` to `float(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` by default reads in terminal inputs as strings. You need to typecast them to the data type you need. And you can just cast all numerical inputs as `floats` that'll just make integers like 3 to 3.00 which won't be an issue in your case.

E.g. `b = float(input("some text"))`
You can do your computations afterwards without any worries.